# Rich media banner. Play video in lightbox

Tags: flash, actionscript

Im about to create a rich meda banner in Flash. On hover a lightbox going to open, fill the screen and play a youtube video. I have worked alot with flash and actionscript, but this is new to me. How would i do this?

Comment: Basically like this: http://www.richmediagallery.com/galleryDetail/?id=35941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a template here: http://www.richmediagallery.com/resources/template-database#ids=|cat685445846item40

Good luck